# Open a GridView contained within a GridView in a popup dialog/window

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm currently working with a very data-rich view that contains several GridViews within each row of the larger, primary GridView. In order to make it more mobile readable, I'd like to add a button/link in one of the columns that will open up one of the larger Grids in a popup window/dialog, thus dramatically reducing the space required for each row.

First, I tried opening a new popup HTML window and copying the hidden GridView code over. This doesn't work as it opens a new tab on mobile devices and the Grid must also be unhidden in the new window. I've also investigated jQuery mobile, but I'd like to avoid importing a new stylesheet and script library for a single functionality on a single view. Finally, I tried nesting the Grid in an expander, which accounts for the length issue but not the issue of width.

Do I have any good options for displaying this Grid effectively in a pop-up window of some kind with jQuery, HTML, SharePoint, or ASP.NET functionality?

Here is some example code of the field I need to display:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" class="createDialog">Show Popup</a>

        <div class="dialogue">
            <p>Need to display all of this..</p>
            <asp:GridView ID="" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="None"
                FooterStyle-CssClass="" OnRowDataBound="" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField FooterStyle-CssClass="" ItemStyle-CssClass="">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: There are many possible solutions for your problem, but why not make a link in the main GridView to `\Popup.aspx?row=x`. Then in Popup.aspx create a GridView with all the content what in the primary grid would be in row x?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Repeater inside a Repeater.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET